# How to test equality of string values?

Tags: java, android

Why does the following 'if()' statement evaluate to true?

```
operand1 = "0";
operand1 = Integer.toBinaryString(Long.valueOf(operand1, 10).intValue());


if(operand1 != "0") {
    display_secondary.setText(operand1.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

The 'if' statement above is evaluated to true and the code inside is run.  Why does that happen?

---

The code below evaluates to false (as expected).

```
operand1 = Integer.toBinaryString(Long.valueOf(operand1, 10).intValue());
operand1 = "0"; 

if(operand1 != "0") {
    display_secondary.setText(operand1.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare `String` in Java use:

```
if(!operand1.equals("0")){

}
```

On the way you are doing it you are comparing the object address not the `String` content.

Comment: Partial answer; the `String` is being `intern`ed.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `String`s are immutable, which allows the language to make *lots* of optimizations. One of these is called `intern`ing: It puts certain `String`s into a shared pool to avoid having identical copies wasting space.

Constant `String`s are always `intern`ed, so using the `==` and `!=` operators (which check to see whether two variables are *the same exact object*, not whether their objects are "equal") on identical constant `String`s (such as `"0"`) will sort-of work. Using `equals` is nearly always preferred.

Your `Integer.toBinaryString` call constructs a brand-new `String` that happens to have the same contents as the constant `String` that's used in the assignment and in the `if` condition but is a different object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s1="hey";
 String s2="hey";
  String s3=new String("hey");
 System.out.println(s1==s2);
  System.out.println(s1==s3);
```

s1,s2 they will both point to the same space in memory..
hence s1==s2 and s1.equals(s2) ....both will be true

s1,s3 will point to different spaces...

hence s1.equals(s3) will be true but s1==s3 is false